# All video recording apps are blurry and slow

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, asus, obs-studio, video-recording

Problem:
My videos are blurry and laggy when I try to record myself. It effects all the recording programs from cheese to obs. For some reason Google Meet is slightly better but still suffers the lag at times.

Laptop specs:
Ubuntu 20.04
16gb ram
AMD ryzen 7
GPU geforce gtx 1660 ti mobile
1.3tb of combined hdd and ssd space

Attempted fixed and misc info:
I have tried installing different drives but nothing has worked. I have also noticed that my Nvidia X Server Settings program doesn't work. It opens to a small 2 inch rectangle with nothing to view. It only has the option to quit.